# Efficient comparison whether set of values is between min-max filters

Tags: algorithms

I'm trying to optimize a practical problem in a database query. Suppose we have a db table`Products` and each product has a few numeric properties. I save the properties values in a different table `ProductProperty` table because the user can add more property types. The user wants to look for products using range filters for each property.

For example if the product has five property types with values `{20, 30, 25, 50, 40}` and the user searches products with values for each property in ranges `{10-35, 20-50, 30-60, 0-100, 10-80}` that product is excluded from results because the third value 25 is not between 30 and 60. The database query for this is not very efficient, it has to go for each product, join `ProductProperty` table, iterate and check every value if it's inside the range.

What I was thinking is to encode the product values `{20, 30, 25, 50, 40}` possibly to some string (I don't think it can fit in any numeric data type) and save them in a column in `Products`, `EncodedValues`.

So my query could then be a simple string comparison

```
select * from products p 
where minEncodedValues <= p.encodedValues AND p.encodedValues <= maxEncodedValues
```

I'm wondering if there could be some transformation of numeric values into a string so `s1<s2` returns `false` if not all values `v1` are less than the corresponding values of `v2`.

Comment: "The database query for this is not very efficient, it has to go for each product, join ProductProperty table, iterate and check every value if it's inside the range", have you thought about indexing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databases are not a silver bullet for every problem under the sun.  You are asking how to answer multi-dimensional [range searches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_searching) efficiently.  Rather than trying to contort your data into a form which lets you solve this with a standard database (a problem for which you probably won't find a good solution), instead, I recommend you look for a data structure that is well-suited to this specific type of query.

In particular, you want a solution to [orthogonal range searching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_searching).  There are standard data structures for this problem.  I expect you will find that, for your specific situation, with orthogonal range queries over a 5-dimensional space, those sophisticated data structures are a bit faster if you are doing an enormous number of queries, but the savings aren't worth it, and it's simpler to simply do a linear scan over all data items: check each data item and see which satisfies the filter.

As far as I can see, nothing forces you to split data across two tables in the form that you mention, so if that makes your data processing workload slow, I recommend a different data format.